# Hide whole Expander if header is empty

Tags: wpf, triggers, datatrigger, wpf-style

I have an Expander WPF control which header's template is a simple TextBlock. I want to hide whole expander if TextBlock.Text (which is filled dynamically from outside) is null or empty.

```
<Expander>
    <Expander.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </Expander.Header>
</Expander>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  can take reference from this example.
[Hide Expander ToggleButton if no child items in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27438153/hide-expander-bullet-if-no-child-items-in-wpf/27439152#27439152)

**Xaml**

```
  <ListBox x:Name="lstbx">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander x:Name="exp">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock>
                </Expander.Header>
                <Expander.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Expander">                          
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter  Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Expander.Style>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**c#**

```
     public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<HeaderList> lst = new List<HeaderList>();
        lst.Add(new HeaderList(){Name= "Header1"});
        lst.Add(new HeaderList() { Name = "Header2" });
        lst.Add(new HeaderList() { });
        lst.Add(new HeaderList() { Name = "Header4" });
        lst.Add(new HeaderList() { });
        lst.Add(new HeaderList() { });
        lst.Add(new HeaderList() { Name = "Header7" });
        this.DataContext = this;
        lstbx.ItemsSource = lst;     
    }
}
public class HeaderList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use binding to Name property to expander visibility with own converter

```
        <Expander Visibility="{Binding Path=Name, Converter={StaticResource EmptyStringToVisibility}}">
             <Expander.Header>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
             </Expander.Header>
        </Expander>
```

Converter for example:

```
    class EmptyStringToVisibility : IValueConverter
    {
         public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
         {
             return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
         }

         public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,  System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
         {
             throw new NotImplementedException();
         }
    }
```

Comment: It is pretty strange but this direct solution does not work for me. Adding a style to the Expander with DataTrigger to TextBox solved the problem.